# flex - add java object bean list in data grid

Tags: java, apache-flex

I am using flex with java.

I am fetching data from DB and put in object bean by setter and getter . and make list of beans.

this list i want to show in data grid in flex.

How should i do that?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use data service. The company currently I'm working in use BlazeDS. You have to read [this easy to understand tutorial](http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/02/01/blazeds-with-remote-objects-example/) to know how it works and how to do. The example used chart, in your case will be datagrid. Just give the returned ArrayCollection from server to your datagrid, you will be fine.